# TypeScript super.super call

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to call `super.super.methodName` in TypeScript. I want to avoid calling `super.methodName`, but I want to call the 2nd ancestor's `methodName` method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not supported by TypeScript. You can however exploit the fact that member functions are on prototype and you can `call` anything with `this` so `SomeBaseClass.prototype.methodName.call(this,/*other args*/)`

Example:

```
class Foo{
    a(){alert('foo')}
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    a(){alert('bar')}
}

class Bas extends Bar{
    a(){Foo.prototype.a.call(this);}
}

var bas = new Bas(); 
bas.a(); // Invokes Foo.a indirectly
```

Comment: ...alerts 'foo'?