# Typescript: super.super call on a protected method

Tags: typescript, overriding, super

I'm trying to extend/override a **protected method** in a class we'll call `ChildClass` a class library's protected override method `tapNode` within a `ParentClass`, whose method calls `super` to the another protected override method `tapNode` in a `GrandParentClass`.

I want to override the behavior such that `ChildClass` can call the `grandParentClass` while extending from the `ParentClass`.

To clarify, we'd have

```
export class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  override tapNode(node?: TreeNode): void {
    custom_stuff();
    super.super.tapNode(node); //What I ideally want to do but can't
}
```

```
export class ParentClass extends ChildClass {
  override tapNode(node?: TreeNode): void {
    [ ...
      inline class-specific code
    ... ]
    super.tapNode(node);
}
```

```
export class GrandParentClass extends ParentClass {
  override tapNode(node?: TreeNode): void {
    [ ...
      inline class-specific code
    ... ]
    super.tapNode(node)
}
```

Some approaches I've looked at so far:

- I'm aware of how one can use the `prototype` method, but this seemingly only applies on public methods, NOT protected methods. (see [TypeScript super.super call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865347/typescript-super-super-call) for more info on that approach)
- I'm aware of mixins and ts-mixer, but that seemingly only works if there's unique method names since you're doing a composition of classes. (see [Typescript: How to extend two classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948400/typescript-how-to-extend-two-classes) )
- I'm aware of the idea of overriding the class-specific code if it's put into it's own method, but that only applies when the code is separated out into it's own method, NOT when it's inline. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536651/314780 as an example).
- I'm aware you generally don't want to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out, the `class` inheritance in TypeScript (and ECMAScript, at least at the time of writing) does not support this use case.

As you also found out, a possible workaround is to fallback to the underlying `prototype`. *However*, doing so for a `protected` method raises an error with TypeScript (as you pointed out, TS allows this for `public` methods only).

That being said, the emitted JS code still contains the `protected` (and even `private`!) methods on the `prototype`, since the [visibility modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#member-visibility) are [only at TS level](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#caveats):

> Like other aspects of TypeScript’s type system, `private` and `protected` [are only enforced during type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?removeComments=true&target=99&ts=4.3.4#code/PTAEGMBsEMGddAEQPYHNQBMCmVoCcsEAHPASwDdoAXLUAM1K0gwQFdZSA7dAKWkoDK4MkSoByBAGJQJLAwAeAWABQIUH0HDSoiTLKUaoUggAW%20DHorUsAOlABJcQlhUy4KpACeoLJzrI8cCwMGxU1ABVPIiwhESpMZEJQTmR4lxFQaQxWMm4IZABbIlIYKlJkTlDlXHgkNFAAbxVQTIAjfABrAEEC5FZOeIBeUAAGAG5mmSw8WAroSFIqb2GAIjMiIk8VieVJ8Ar01ncAgAoASkaAXxVr3dUwGoQAYWpMHBgCYn1rekZmNg4eUi0Vi2icoBWJCsNBWoA6WE8AHcAiEwmBgTEtDovtDaMZQLM6PEoQZbA5wSk0q5SO4vD4-AEghZoJwLGYEIRwNBoqAzFRwCZCFUIlFMXECdSiAhId8YZgclx0PsiiVqOVOAAaUAFLAsxWgKiC35MFigfC0FKgSAVVDTSyk%20W5dB4fplHVVR6gF7xJrKFotEk-HXIRE9PoDUDDcaTAPTWaceaLZYQlmoPBbHYx-KcQ7HPDnK43FQqfY5%20IMDDISPJLCIuqoc47UsuUCofAME3Vzi1r3URvF5QV5A2STtPDdXqunZDgDaYlHnTDrrEAF0dm28B3mDZg6HJwN1%202-hg57ulwNV2NQGoZbjYfNrYiENBwEFaojFiZQK08C-4fFKTVCozWfTgfFgLkeT5AUqiAA).
>
> This means that JavaScript runtime constructs like `in` or simple property lookup can still access a `private` or `protected` member

Therefore, ignoring the TS error, the runtime works as expected:

```
class GrandParentClass {
    protected tapNode(node?: TreeNode): void {
        /* ...
          inline class-specific code
        ... */
        console.log("GrandParent", node)
    }
}

class ParentClass extends GrandParentClass {
    override tapNode(node?: TreeNode): void {
        /* ...
          inline class-specific code
        ... */
        console.log("Parent", node)
        super.tapNode(node);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    override tapNode(node?: TreeNode): void {
        //custom_stuff();
        //super.super.tapNode(node); //What I ideally want to do but can't

        console.log("Child", node)

        // @ts-ignore In order to break the class inheritance contract,
        // we have to break the TS visibility modifier contract as well...
        GrandParentClass.prototype.tapNode.call(this, node)
        //                         ~~~~~~~ Error: Property 'tapNode' is protected and only accessible through an instance of class 'ChildClass'. This is an instance of class 'GrandParentClass'.
    }
}

new ChildClass().tapNode("some tree node")

type TreeNode = string
```

...correctly outputs:

```
[LOG]: "Child",  "some tree node" 
// (No Parent log)
[LOG]: "GrandParent",  "some tree node"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOYB2ATACmeBTJAXAwuFNAN4BQ0l0ADvAPa5bCMrS5jUBydKWAFEh5YA-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-LSWmlKhi7AZaAwGFrnBKRrwDNbNXwmx2cj6BdpLhfLgA-G+3q-QACi-Rj4jQ9B+fegdslvBtapga6MMwWCsKk0YWDq46FlAXZROm9CfHE0KTlG5hMsghbRq42w1DaHrwoiNr+BIsLZjAyBquE+aYXQ2FZl+C7ooRBigiUSBYLqUKwgROy8tuAKJBELJDNILy8IkbxkH2ziTOS0zQAAvNATIDEgcTQGQQA)

Comment: Thanks, the key parts I learned here as you mention was putting in a @ts-ignore for this scenario, and using the `.call` method passing in both the instance and other parameters in.